# Grafana : Network Error: undefined(undefined)

Tags: java, database, jmeter, performance-testing

I encounter a problem in creating a Grafana data source , I started my Grafana Server, I choose datatype:InfluxDB, HttpSetting Url : http://localhost:8086, Access: direct...when I click on add data, I got: Test Failed
Network Error: undefined(undefined).
When I change the Access to Proxy I got: Test Failed
Network Error: Bad Gateway(502)

Every help will be appreciated

Comment: For me, it gave this error in Chrome but worked fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error - Network Error: undefined(undefined) - while connecting Grafana to Influxdb. In my case, everything was working fine until I moved Grafana to HTTPS. Checking the Firefox developer tools console gave a hint and the real problem was mixed content in the page (HTTPS and HTTP).

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://influxdb.mydomain.com:8086query?d...."

More details here [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

Answer (score 0):

After searching google again and again.

Here are the several solutions:

1. Update the "Access" in the data sources.
   Try to switch between "Server (Default)" and "Browser"
2. Check your influxdb query. Sometimes the query is so slow, and grafana timeout in 30 seconds when querying the data

   I use this solution to fix my issue. Because I use the regex during search. It is so slow.
3. Try the following.
   Edit the /etc/grafana/grafana.ini:

   Find and change the followings to:

```
# How long the data proxy should wait before timing out default is 30 
(seconds)
timeout = 120
```